# How exactly does a high hat foot pedal work for an electronic drum kit?

Tags: audio

I've been building my own e-kit and the high hat pedal I have has been working correctly up until recently. It's from an Alesis iDM-02 kit, but the module I'm currently using is the Alesis Trigger IO. The pedal is supposed to send a signal once when it's depressed, but it's been glitching out, sending signals all over. I opened it up and there seems to be just a simple switch of some kind in there with just two wires leading to the mono jack.

I want to know exactly how this thing works. How is it that it sends a signal? How is it that that signal, sent through a simple mono cable, can be interpreted as a toggle, switching the high hat between open and closed? (the pedal is still working fine in that regard.) And finally, what exactly is the malfunctioning piece? I mean, what do i search ebay for to find a replacement?

Here's a video to help explain:
https://www.facebook.com/video/video.php?v=10100457462623591&saved
and if a better picture would help i can snip the thing off, maybe break it open, and take one.

Comment: No, it is not a piezo. I have constructed many drums using piezo sensors and this is different. Yes, there are a lot of microcontrollers in the module, the Alesis Trigger io, which does all of the interpreting, but that is not what I'm asking about. I'm asking about the signal and how it's generated, before it's ever interpreted.

Comment: That IS the answer, to the question i'm trying to ask!

Comment: uh.. no. My question is about the pedal. The rest of the kit is working fine. I broke it open and it looks to just be a simple switch. When the pedal's down, a circuit is connected, when it's up, the circuit is broken.

Comment: @RyanFougner Not familiar with the set-up described, but if the "mono jack" is designed for electret microphone or phantom powered microphone input, then it supplies a small bias voltage to the wire pair, through a resistor. Opening or closing the switch would change the voltage across that  resistor, thus available as high and low pulses for a GPIO in one of the microcontrollers in there to interpret.

Comment: A glitching switch could be due to dirty contacts, contacts which are not being mechanically moved properly (spring lost, part broken which leads to the contacts not being firmly pushed together, etc.)

Comment: I would guess a Hall-Effect sensor. They can detect position, velocity, etc. by the presence of a magnetic field. Notice any magnets when you cracked that sucker open?

Answer (score 1):

For the kits I've worked with, the hihat is one MIDI note, with onset and velocity information, followed by a note off command later .  The hihat pedal is used to control an additional MIDI CC which controls how "open" the hihat is.  MIDI signals are sent over a fairly simple serial bus.

Answer (score 1):

**There are two types of Hi Hat pedals ( controllers ).**

**The cheaper ones** are just switches ( closed switch = closed hats and visa versa ... and they are obviously used in conjunction with a hi hat pad so you end up with just 3 basic sounds: Open, Closed and Pedal )

**The more expensive ones** are variable and there are a few types of these AFAIK. I think the majority use a sensor of some sort - sorry I don't know what it is but I think it's a kind of non mechanical resistor ( the technology looks sort of similar to a computer keyboard contact to me but after that I don't know ). I think the majority of these ultimately work on resistance.

**You have to use the correct pedal with your module.** A switch pedal wont work with a variable module ( usually ) and to a certain extent the same is true the other way around, and there's lots more to it that that because resistances for pedals and modules differ in terms of what's considered Open and Closed. Also for the switch modules some work in the reverse convention to others.

Your module is a variable unit sending controller midi data on CC4 (I think). You map the open, closed and pedal sounds to the same midi note and then CC4 does the magic of controlling between the open and closed sounds, but then of course your destination module or soft synth needs to be completable with variable too I'd say ( because there are no sounds on the Trigger IO as you know ). I don't know if a switch controller will work with the Trigger IO or not so you might have to use something like the Alesis Realhat pedal with it, that's the seup I have and I know it works.

Answer (score 0):

This answers what I think is the fundamental question you ask:

> How is it that it sends a signal? How is it that that signal, sent through a simple mono cable, can be interpreted as a toggle, switching the high hat between open and closed?

I would assume that the "brain" (as the drum computer seems to be called) measures the resistance of the switch (by feeding a small current to it via a resistor).  If the switch is closed, the current will flow (I'm assuming one side of the switch is grounded through the jack plug and the other side of the switch is on the tip of the jack) and the brain will read zero volts. If the switch is open then the brain will read some positive voltage (whatever the other end of the resistor is connected to).

Based on that signal, the brain will play different samples when you hit the hi-hat. And potentially play a "closing sample" when you press the pedal. And if it's clever, do some filtering and envelope shaping if you press the pedal while the "open" sample is still playing, to emulate the "quenching" effect of bringing the two cymbals together.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my opinion on the basic functionality:

As far as I remember from my drumm class, high hat is used in closed/opened positions as well as some tricks come during opening/closing - as it gives a special and unique sounds.

Therefore, I would expect the receiver - the one that triggers on the switch signals from the pedal to recognize and differentiate all the states: HI, LOW, and LOW->HI, and HI->LOW transitions. This would allow generating sounds accordingly.

My guess is that the wiring/jack may lose contact, or wires may be broken - a bad contact. I had similar problem with a MIDI keyboard. Additionally, make sure that you start your system with the high hat in "open" position.

Also, you may try connecting a different pedal just me make sure the system is working properly.